# Set a dataframe column's rows to some data based on a different dataframe based on dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with Dates, Names and Notes but I wanted to add which Team they we're in for the given date.

The Team Data frame would have Name, Team Name, Team Start Date, Team End Date.

Problem is that team members move teams constantly so I haven't found a way in pandas to get the Team Column to work properly.

In excel this would have worked with the Filter formula or a simple Sumifs combined with Index/Match or in sql with a view.

How would I get a Team column in the first Dataframe?

Is this possible in python?

```
dfNotes = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':'6/30/2021 7/11/2021 7/12/2021 7/13/2021 7/14/2021 7/15/2021'.split(),
    'Name': 'Emp1 Emp2 Emp3 Emp1 Emp2 Emp3'.split(),
    'Case Notes':'19281080  19356855 19454005   19289960    19206939    19472141'.split()
})

dfTeams = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': 'Emp1   Emp1    Emp1    Emp2    Emp2    Emp2    Emp3    Emp3    Emp3'.split(),
    'Team': '2  3   1   1   1   5   1   2   1'.split(),
    'Team Start Date':  '7/5/2020   4/12/2021   4/28/2021   1/1/2020    3/22/2021   6/4/2021    3/9/2020    11/25/2020  11/30/2020'.split(),
    'Team End Date':    '4/11/2021  4/27/2021   12/31/2021  3/21/2021   6/3/2021    12/31/2021  11/24/2020  11/29/2021  12/31/2021'.split()
})
```

Comment: can you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? (expected output)

Comment: Expected output would have been something like

`Date Name Case Notes Team
6/30/2021 Emp1 19281080 1
7/11/2021 Emp2 19356855 5
7/12/2021 Emp3 19454005 1
7/13/2021 Emp1 19289960 1
7/14/2021 Emp2 19206939 5
7/15/2021 Emp3 19472141 1`